# Need help for routing in asp.net webform

Tags: asp.net, url-routing

i want to achieve few redirection like
when user will type this `www.mysite.com/label/uk` or `www.mysite.com/label.aspx/uk` then my labeluk.aspx will load or

when user will type this `www.mysite.com/label/us` or `www.mysite.com/label.aspx/us` then my labelus.aspx will load or

when user will type this `www.mysite.com/label/fr` or `www.mysite.com/label.aspx/fr` then my labelfr.aspx will load.

so please tell me how do i define pattern for routing like

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("Source1", "label/{ID}", "~/labeluk.aspx");
```

RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("Source1", "label/{ID}", "~/labelus.aspx");

i am not being able to figure out how to achieve it by routing. please help me to form the maproute. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can look into URL Rewriting on the web or SEO Urls

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/URL-Rewriting-in-ASPNET.aspx

Comment: basically i want to solve it by routing feature instead of writing code to handle url rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this..

keep one route (in Global) as

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("Source", "label/{ID}, "~/label.aspx");
```

so all will resolve /label.aspx, then on label.aspx check ID param e.g.

```
Page.RouteData.Values.ContainsKey("ID")
```

and depending on whether it's uk, fr or us do

```
HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("/labeluk.aspx", false);
```

alternatively not even need to have /label.aspx just check ID param in Global and do RewritePath there